# is it bad practice to access vuex state properties directly (without getters), and why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, getter-setter, vuex

If here is my store.js file:

```
const state = {
  count: 0,
  loggedIn: false
}

const mutations = {
  UP_COUNT(state) {
      state++;
  }
}

const actions = {
  upCount({ commit }) {
    commit('UP_COUNT');
  }
}
```

Let's say to increase state `count` from one of my Vue components, I will call an action which then commits a mutation:

```
this.$store.dispatch('upCount');
```

Then let's say in another Vue component, I want to use the state count:

```
<div class="count">{{ this.$store.state.count }}</div>
```

What is wrong with this style? (vs using `$this.store.getters`...)

Comment: I think my answer on this post provides some (albeit my opinion of) a reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191231/why-is-state-visible-to-components

Comment: thanks @webnoob, that makes sense.  My understanding is that it would be OK if you're grabbing a single variable... But if needing to filter state data and return, it's best to do that in a getter so you don't need to duplicate that filter code everywhere you call it.

Comment: Whilst this question might be opinion based, I think it merits some thoughts on it. Surely following best practice isn't opinion based? There must be a valid reason for the developer of said package to make it best practice.

Comment: @webnoob https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337031/primarily-opinion-based-on-best-practice-questions

Comment: @thanksd - Fair enough, thanks. I'll add the last close vote in that case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I pointed out on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47191438/261682) there is no hard and fast way you **must** do things but following a practice and going with it is best.

Using getters might seem over-kill but you can change the data behind the scenes using getters as long as the getter name remains the same and this saves a lot of work re-factoring and trying to find all the references to other places where you might have used `this.$store.state.module.someValue`.

It also allows you to return data based on mutiple state variables into one getter i.e

```
`isAllowed: 'getIsAllowed'`
```

could be based on

```
getIsAllowed (state) {
  return state.loggedIn && state.hasPermission && state.somethingElse
}
```

You can change what `isAllowed` is based on easily in one place rather than using each state variable in your components and doing the logic multiple times.

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/persisting-user-authentication-with-vuex-in-vue-b1514d5d3278) article uses a getter like the following: `isLoggedIn: state => state.isLoggedIn`. this doesnt make sense to me, as in `state.isLoggedIn` should be some kind of private property, because it is not clear which one to use. So I think getters indeed only make sense for filtering, mapping etc since we do not have an OOP-like getters/setters mechanic here

Comment: [another article](https://codeburst.io/vuex-getters-are-great-but-dont-overuse-them-9c946689b414) which says kind of the same. In other words, I think "getters" is a rather poor term choice from vuex's side because it leads to confusion like this. sry for duplicate comment

Comment: @phil294 however, and as mentioned in the answer, using `getters` even for direct state access, will pay off later for refactoring.